# How to have button clicked before page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

The logic I am doing right now is this below to have the button clicked after the page is loaded. Is it possible to speed up the time when the button is clicked after the page is loaded to make it look like it happens instantly, or can I click the button before the page is loaded to make sure that what the button shows after being clicked is instantly showed after page is loaded.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('id').click() }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this unless you create the button in javascript but also if you do that, you would have to wait for the page to load, to get the div where you want to insert your button to. If you put it outside your onload, and create a button in you body for example, it'll may be pressed a little bit faster

Comment: you can't get the id of something that hasn't been loaded...

Comment: If that click invokes other script then there is no way to speed it up. The other script needs to have loaded also. Really not enough known about the page or what this click does for a reasonable answer. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: And clicking a button on a page as soon as it loads seems to be a bit odd - why not simply code the result into the page in the first place.  That will be fastest.

Comment: @Hektor how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: Whatever your document.getElementById('id').click()  function does, you could achieve by simply running that function on page load, You might start by renaming the div because a div whose id is 'id' looks like trouble. So if you renamed that function to  myDivFunction then after defining the function in the page simply call it underneath with myDivFunction(); or put in <body onload="myDivFunction()"> to ensure all necessary elements are loaded before the function is called.